# how to ignore http block from https hosted nodejs app - can we do webpack config/react dependencies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

My application hosted in test which is secured and not loading lot of css/images from http content: -> getting console error as

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://oxxxxx.com/#token=x' was loaded over HTTPS, 
but requested an insecure font 'http://localhost:3000/node_modules/semantic-ui-css/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.ttf?'.
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

bundle.js:35 Mixed Content: 
The page at xxxxx was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://localhost:8080/xxxx/[object%20Object]'. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Great if you have solution in webpack.config or any libraries to work with react

Comment: If you're using webpack, try adding a proxy.

Comment: Also it seems your XHR request url is wrong, it says `http://localhost:8080/xxxx/[object%20Object]`

Comment: But why is your https page, requesting a font from localhost?